# C++ operation too confusing?

Tags: c++, operations

I can't seem to understand this operation. 
What is the output of the following code?
I've tried interpreting why b has two different values one as b=1+2 and the other as b=2, since a++ should equal to a=1+a ,then the cout is asking for ++b, which one should it should equal to, b=2-1 or b=3-1?

```
int a=3;
int b=2;
b=a++;
cout<<++b;
```

I know the answer to this question is 4. But i can't get my head around it.

Comment: Just break it down in to it's respective parts in the following way:

`int a = 3; // a is currently 3`
`int b = 2; // b is currently 2`
`b = a++; // post-increment operator. Assign a to b then increment a (a = 4 now)`
`cout << ++b; // pre-increment operator. increment b by 1 and then print the result (4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But i can't get my head around it.

When that happens you can try to simplify the statements/expressions.

---

Due to the use of the post-increment operator,

```
b = a++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
b = a;
a = a+1;
```

---

Due to the use of the pre-increment operator,

```
cout<<++b;
```

is equivalent to:

```
b = b+1;
cout << b;
```

---

Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Yeah that made sense. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> why b has two different values

`b` does not have two different values. `b`, `a`, and everything else, always has one value, at any given time. It might have different values at different times, but it always has just one value, at a given time.

Since `a` is 3, then:

```
b=a++;
```

Sets `b` to 3, since the post-increment operation modifies the value of `a` after the value of `a` is used in the expression.

```
cout<<++b;
```

This outputs 4, because the pre-increment operation modifies the value of `b` before it is used in the expression. Since `b` starts out with `3`, it gets incremented to 4, then used in the expression.